# How to send activity instance to module in a constructor in dagger2

Tags: java, android, dagger-2

I am using `dagger2` in my application. I have created module, component which is being in my entire application so I am initializing it in the `application` class.

Below is my module, component of dagger2 which are helping for resolving dependencies.

**NetComponent.java**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AppModule.class, NetModule.class})
public interface NetComponent {
    void inject(AuthenticationActivity authenticationActivity);

    void inject(PaymentActivity paymentActivity);
}
```

**AppModule.java**

```
@Module
public class AppModule {

    private Application application;

    public AppModule(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Application providesApplication() {
        return application;
    }
}
```

**NetModule.java**

```
@Module
public class NetModule {

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    SharedPreferences providesSharedPreferences(Application application) {
        return PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(application);
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Cache provideOkHttpCache(Application application) {
        int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
        Cache cache = new Cache(application.getCacheDir(), cacheSize);
        return cache;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Gson provideGson() {
        GsonBuilder gsonBuilder = new GsonBuilder();
        gsonBuilder.setFieldNamingPolicy(FieldNamingPolicy.LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
        return gsonBuilder.create();
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    OkHttpClient provideOkHttpClient(Cache cache) {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
        okHttpClient.newBuilder()
                //.addNetworkInterceptor(REWRITE_CACHE_CONTROL_INTERCEPTOR)
                .cache(cache)
                .build();
        return okHttpClient;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("authRetrofit")
    Retrofit provideAuthRetrofit(Gson gson, OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .baseUrl(PAYMENT_SERVICE)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
        return retrofit;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    @Named("paymentRetrofit")
    Retrofit providePaymentRetrofit(Gson gson, OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .baseUrl(LOGIN_SERVICE)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .build();
        return retrofit;
    }


}
```

**AppApplication.java**

```
public class AppApplication extends Application {

    private NetComponent mNetComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        mNetComponent = DaggerNetComponent.builder()
                .appModule(new AppModule(this))
                .build();
    }

    public NetComponent getmNetComponent() {
        return mNetComponent;
    }

}
```

**Validator.java**

```
@Module
public class Validator {

    @Provides
    com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator providesValidator(Application application) {
        return new com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator(application);
    }
}
```

I want to pass activity instance to the constructor of `Validator` in which I am using it.

Suppose I want to inject `Validator` in `MainActivity.java` then constructor should have `MainActivity` instance.

What approach should I take for this ? Should I initialize the dagger dependency in an `activity` for this and Do I need to create a new component for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create constructor for your ValidatorModule:

```
@Module
public class Validator {

    private final Activity activity;

    public Validator(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Provides
    com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator providesValidator() {
        return new com.mobsandgeeks.saripaar.Validator(activity);
    }
}
```

Let me know if it is what you are looking for

Comment: Dagger2 is showing a warning `ValidationComponent validationComponent = DaggerValidationComponent.builder()
                .validatorModule(getValidatorModule())
                .build();` when adding `validatorModule(getValidatorModule())`